# SCILAB-loop-invalid index

Tags: loops, indexing, scilab

I have a problem with my code. Even though it is working correctly error 21 is still being displayed. I have two independent loops in my code and only one of them is working.

```
for i=1:n
int1=INT1(i,1);
int2=INT1(i+1,1);
if int1<int2
    INT2(i,:)=INT1(i,:)
end
```

I guess the third line int2=INT1(i+1,1) is not absolutely correct, which cause that my second loop doesn't work.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What line causes the error? (Scilab tells you that). What size does INT1 have? There is only one look in your code block; what second loop are you talking about? You have only one "end" in your code, but there are two blocks that need to be ended: "for" and "if".

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide `INT1` and `n`, I had to guess to make a working example. Apart from this a final `end` was missing from your code:

```
n=10;
INT1=rand(n+1,1);
for i=1:n
  int1=INT1(i,1);
  int2=INT1(i+1,1);
  if int1<int2
    INT2(i,:)=INT1(i,:)
  end  //termination of if statement
end  //termination of for loop
```